# Forcing the user to go through another page before getting to the one in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

For example, if the user tries to access a `Main` action and enters `mySite/Main` in the address bar, I would like force that to route to `mySite/beforeMain`, which would then automatically redirect to `Main` after some processing. How can I do this with route mapping, or is this possible in other ways? I don't want to have query string parameters in the URL, or use TempData/etc. in case cookies are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use [Url Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

Alternatively you could use `RedirectToAction`:

```
public ActionResult Main()
{
    if(Request.QueryString["redirected"].ToString() != "true")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("beforeMain", "mySite");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Then your `beforeMain` action could be:

```
public ActionResult BeforeMain()
{
     //do some stuff
     return RedirectToAction("Main",  new { redirected = "true" });
}
```

Then when you hit main the second time it will skip the redirect and you wont end up in a loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out Url Rewrite, but besides that for now: the problem with redirecting from main is that I don't know whether or not this is the first time I've redirected, since `beforeMain` would redirect back. Without a check, there would be a redirect loop--but without route values or TempData, I can't check for anything that I can think of.

Comment: Is it possible to have the query string be not appended to the URL? That was part of the problem I was having--didn't want to use route values because of that appended query string.

Comment: You could use the session to store a value instead i guess

Comment: HTTP is stateless, you need some way of persisting data across postbacks... Why do you want to hide the query string? There is [UrlRewriting.net](http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html), you can rewrite a 'clean' url (without querystrings) to one that has the querystring. The user wont see it in their address bar. Not sure how this works with MVC though i'm afraid